# How does solidity detect that Ether has been sent from one address to the other address?

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-design, ether

I have learned solidity. And I have one question.

How does contract detect that Ether has been sent from one address to the other address?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. What do you mean by "detect" ? Either ether is sent from A to B outside from the contract, or a function was called. You should add a little more information to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Each contract has an implicit 'default function' `function ()`.  If this function is modified as `payable` then the contract can receive fund through that function from a trivial send transaction.

If the default function implements code, then that code will be also be run.  However the default amount of gas in a send transaction can do little more that trigger an event.  Anything more and the sender needs to be aware of the higher amount of gas required.

```
contract SimplySend {
    event Paid(uint);
    function () payable {
        Paid(msg.value);
    }
}

contract NeedExtraGas {
    event Paid(uint);
    uint total;
    function () payable {
        total += msg.send;
        Paid(msg.value);
    }
}
```